# Angular2 select with ngValue null

Tags: angular

Here's what I'm trying to do: I want a select list bound to an array of objects with ngValue, but the first option needs to be a "None" option with a `null` value.

Model:

```
this.managers = [
  { id: null, name: "(None)" },
  { id: 1, name: "Jeffrey" },
  { id: 2, name: "Walter" },
  { id: 3, name: "Donnie" }
  ];

this.employee = {
  name: "Maude",
  managerId: null
};
```

View:

```
<select [(ngModel)]="employee.managerId">
    <option *ngFor="#manager of managers" [ngValue]="manager.id">{{ manager.name }}</option>
  </select>
```

On load, the list correctly binds to the "None" element. But if you change to a different item and back, the model value now switches to a string of `0: null`. This is pretty inconvenient; it means I have to intercept the value and change it to a null manually before I attempt to save it to the server.

Here's a Plunker with a demo: http://plnkr.co/edit/BH96RWZmvbbO63ZAxgNX?p=preview

This was pretty easily done in Angular 1 with an extra `<option value="">None</option>`

This seems like it would be a pretty common scenario, and yet I've been unable to find any solutions. I've also tried adding an `<option [ngModel]="null">None</option>`, but it results in the same `0: null` value.

Any suggestions?

Comment: I guess you should create a bug report.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For me it is really looks like a bug, but I if you are looking for fast solution, you can simply convert `null` identifier to `string`. It should solve the problem but you should do some additional moves to make that work.

See example [Plnkr example](http://plnkr.co/edit/KNy5GzGyEeXTeLq97bvE?p=preview)

Or if you are going to do that in the way you mention from ng1,
 you can do like this: [Plnkr example](http://plnkr.co/edit/vYTNLNEuZoRDsyG8mtH9?p=preview)

I know that it is not best solution, but hope will help you before this bug will be fixed by NG team!

- https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/10349
- https://github.com/angular/angular/pull/12026

Comment: I'd forgotten about ngModelChange, which at least helps me with a workaround. Thanks!

Comment: I have exactly the same issue, but your workaround doesn't work if are using a class as your model. THan you have specified the data type for your property and the compiler doesn't let you compile the code which compares a int to a string.. so I better hope that they fix this soon..

Comment: Just viewing changelog of Angular2, and this is fixed in [2.2.1](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#bug-fixes-1)

Comment: By the way, I do not see any documentation for `ngValue` in Angular 2. In the [official guide](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/forms.html) they even use regular `value`

Answer (score 7):

I will redirect you to TabascoMustang's reddit answer, I implement his solution and work magnificent:

[TabascoMustang's reddit answer](https://www.reddit.com/r/Angular2/comments/4a196y/ngfor_select_list_with_null_option/#thing_t1_d6w3k4c)

> this should work (updated for current ng2 rc):

```
<select [ngModel]="audit.managerId || ''" (ngModelChange)="audit.managerId = $event">
  <option value="">Please Select</option>
  <option *ngFor="let contact of audit.contacts">{{ contact.name }}
  </option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of the string 'null' I created a blank object to compare to later on in my TypeScript.

In component:

```
blankObject = {
   toString() {
      return 'blank object';
   }
};

isBlank() {
    return this.filter.searchValue == null || this.filter.searchValue === this.blankObject;
}
```

In Template:

```
<select [(ngModel)]="filter.searchValue">
   <option [ngValue]="blankObject"></option>
   <option *ngFor="let item of filter.selectOptions" [ngValue]="item.value">
                {{item.label}}
   </option>
</select>`
```

Comment: This is awesome. By using [ngValue] in the for loop it also ensures that the type is the same type as what's coming from the api, in this case a number type, otherwise it would have been a default string type.

Answer (score 1):

As of now there is an [open issue in the github repository](https://github.com/driftyco/ionic/issues/9682) for this.

As a work around I found adding `ngModelChange` is the easiest way to set the value to null in the view without having to add anything to the component.

View:

```
<select [(ngModel)]="employee.managerId"
        (ngModelChange)="employee.managerId = $event ? $event : null">
    <option *ngFor="#manager of managers" [value]="manager.id">{{ manager.name }}</option>
</select>
```

*note that `ngValue` is now `value`*

Answer (score 0):

Change [ngValue] to just [value]

Answer (score 0):

I've tried using [value], but it didn't work. Then I changed [ngValue] to ng-value. It works :)