# Angular2: Parse input/select string value into strong typed value

Tags: parsing, typescript, angular, boolean

I'm searching for over a day now to get the right answer, but I'm still a bit clueless. The question is really simple: I have a model with a property which is a boolean. I map that property to a select, which allows the user to select the right value (true, false or null). Angular is actually returning a string. To get concrete:

I have the following component:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'clientlist',
  templateUrl: './app/components/clientlist/clientlist.html'
})

export class ClientListComponent {  
   searchRequest : ClientSearchRequest;
}
```

I have the following tempalte:

```
<select [(ngModel)]="searchRequest.online" class="form-control" (onchange)="search()" numberBinder>
    <option value="">Select</option>
    <option value="true">Online</option>
    <option value="false">Offline</option>
</select>
```

And the search request model class:

```
export class ClientSearchRequest {
name: string;
online: boolean;
status: string;
page: number;
pageSize: number;

constructor() {
    this.name = "";
    this.online = null;
    this.status = "";
    this.page = 1;
    this.pageSize = 50;
}
```

}

When I let the model get filled, the online field is set with a string ("true"). How to fix this? What is the right approach without creating extra components etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would try to use the ngValue directive. This way you will be able to use an object instead of a string for values:

```
<select [(ngModel)]="searchRequest.online" class="form-control" 
        (onchange)="search()" numberBinder>
  <option [ngValue]="'null'">Select</option>
  <option [ngValue]="true">Online</option>
  <option [ngValue]="false">Offline</option>
</select>
```

Using a `null` value doesn't work so you need a workaround for this. See this question for more details:

- [Angular2 select with ngValue null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36781906/angular2-select-with-ngvalue-null)

Comment: When I apply this, I recieve the following error: Can't bind to 'ngValue' since it isn't a known native property

Comment: Which version of Angular2 do you use?

Comment: AH! good question, beta 11, I will upgrade to the current version.

Comment: I don't know on which version it was added but in beta14 ng-value was renamed to ngValue. See the changelog: https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md

Comment: I took me a while to test it, but the upgrade indeed fixed the first problem in the comments. Its now mapping to a boolean. No I will try to do the null value. Thanks a lot :)

Comment: I didn't really fix the null issue. Since my model has a boolean and angular converts the value to a string, my code doesnt compile if I compare a string with a boolean.. So I ended up in changing it into a number an using the values -1, 0, 1